# Why the size of the encrypted data using AES is much bigger?

Tags: python, aes, size

my implementation is in python ,after using the AES encryption algorithm on a file with size 111kb  the encrypted data size after AES is about 139 kb. I need a help and ask if it’s normal or not.

[image]

I tried to handle the size but it doesn’t work. is there anything wrong in writing the code that maybe maximize the size?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Copy and paste your code within the question. To ensure the code is properly displayed, select the code and click on the code sample icon in the editor. It shows up as `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

You are b85 encoding the encrypted data which increases the size of the data. Moreover, I am not sure why you b85 encode the iv along with the encrypted data.

Comment: At first i used base64 and the size was much bigger . Then tried to use b85 and the size becomes slightly small than base64. I don’t know where is the problem and how people use AES to get the size like the plaintext as they said.

Comment: @MasterPiece That's the problem. If you change the binary result into ascii, it will get larger, because that's how encoding binary data in ascii format using b85 or base64 do. If you don't want that, do not encode it, write the binary data into the file.